# SQL Server Select LIKE Regex Equivalent to '?' or '\\s*'

Tags: sql-server, regex, select, sql-server-2012

I have a short question is there an equivalent to `?` in SQL Server SELECT LIKE regex?

I try to select data from table in SQL Server 2012. Example data from column

```
...
<SOMETHING>
    <UNINTERESTING>test</UNINTERESTING>
    <INTERESTING>searchedString</INTERESTING>
    <SOMEMORE>
       <PROBLEMHERE>searchedString</PROBLEMHERE>
    </SOMEMORE>
...
```

or

```
...
<SOMETHING>
    <UNINTERESSTING>test</UNINTERESSTING>
    <INTERESING>searchedString but nevertheless wrong</INTERESTING>
    <SOMEMORE>
       <PROBLEMHERE>searchedString</PROBLEMHERE>
    </SOMEMORE>
...
```

I can select these with

```
LIKE '%<INTERESING>searchedString</INTERESTING>%'
```

everything works fine, but it is possible that the value between `<INTERESTING>` ends sometimes with one or more spaces

e.g.

```
<INTERESING>searchedString </INTERESTING>
<INTERESING>searchedString         </INTERESTING>
```

If I try to select with `%`, then I got rows, where the search string is found but not between interesting, or between two interestings, or I get the wrong rows like

```
<INTERESING>searchedString but nevertheless wrong</INTERESTING>
```

I tried to select with `_`, `%`, `[ ]` but nothing of them get me the correct rows.

Is there an equivalent in SQL Server `LIKE` regex for `?` (none or one-time)
or anything like \s* (whitespaces, can be none, one or more-times)

Thanks in advance

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you problem is spaces... just replace / remove those and your like statement should work and you can avoid other parsing and worrying about REGEX all together.

`where replace(column,' ','') like'%<INTERESING>searchedString</INTERESTING>%'`

If you expect `TAB` or `NEWLINE` then use replace and `CHAR(10)` and `CHAR(13)`

`where replace(replace(replace(column,' ',''),char(10),''),char(13),'') like'%<INTERESING>searchedString</INTERESTING>%'`

Comment: No sweat @Hans.Olo

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an equivalent in SQL Like Regex

No. You should use SQL Server's [XQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server) to parse the XML and extract the XML Element values, and *then* use LIKE for examining the element value.